# renaming with find

Tags: linux, shell

I managed to find several files with the find command.
the files are of the type **file_sakfksanf.txt, file_afsjnanfs.pdf, file_afsnjnjans.cpp,**
now I want to rename them with the rename and -exec command to
 **mywish_sakfksanf.txt, mywish_afsjnanfs.pdf, mywish_afsnjnjans.cpp**
that only the first prefix is changed. I am trying for some time, so don't blame me for being stupid.

Comment: If you create a script to rename one file, you can then use that script with find.

Comment: We never accuse people of being stupid.  Lazy, perhaps, but never stupid.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read through the `-exec` section of the `man` pages for `find` you will come across the `{}` string that allows you to use the matches as arguments within `-exec`. This will allow you to use `rename` on your `find` matches in the following way:

```
find . -name 'file_*' -exec rename 's/file_/mywish_/' {} \;
```

From the manual:

> -exec **command** ;
>
> Execute  command;  true if 0 status is returned.  All following
>   arguments to find are taken to be arguments to the command until an
>   argument consisting of `;' is encountered. The string`{}' is replaced
>   by the current file name being processed everywhere it occurs in the
>   arguments to the command, not just in arguments where it is alone, as
>   in some versions of find.  Both of these constructions  might  need to
>   be escaped (with a `\') or quoted to protect them from expansion by
>   the shell.  See the EXAMPLES section for examples of the use of the
>   -exec option.  The specified command is run once for each matched file.  The command is executed in the starting directory.There are
>   unavoidable security problems surrounding use of the -exec action; 
>   you  should use the -execdir option instead.

Although you asked for a find/exec solution, as [Mark Reed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/797049/mark-reed) suggested, you might want to consider piping your results to `xargs`. If you do, make sure to use the `-print0` option with `find` and either the `-0` or `-null` option with `xargs` to avoid unexpected behaviour resulting from whitespace or shell metacharacters appearing in your file names. Also, consider using the `+` version of `-exec` (also in the manual) as this is the POSIX spec for `find` and should therefore be more portable if you are wanting to run your command elsewhere (not **always** true); it also builds its command line in a way similar to `xargs` which should result in less invocations of `rename`.

Comment: It would be more efficient to use either `xargs` or the `+` option to the `find -exec`: `find . -name 'file_*' -exec rename 's/file_/mywish_/' {} +`  Then it only runs rename once or a few times, as opposed to once per file.  Also, this is assuming a particular rename command syntax, which is system-dependent; it might be `rename file_ mywish_` instead of `rename 's/file_/mywish_/'`

Comment: @MarkReed: Included mention of the `+` version and an `xargs` alternative. I'm sure the OP can amend the `rename` syntax to conform to their own system if they need to.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there's a way you can do this with just find, you'll need to create a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
NEW=`echo $1 | sed -e 's/file_/mywish_/'`
mv $1 ${NEW}
```

THen you can:

```
find ./ -name 'file_*' -exec my_script {} \;
```