# Use find to copy files to a new folder

Tags: linux, bash, find

I'm searching for a `find` command to copy all wallpaper files that look like this:

3245x2324.png (All Numbers are just a placeholder)
3242x3242.jpg

I'm in my `/usr/share/wallpapers` folder and there are many sub folders with the files I want to copy.
There are many like "screenshot.png" and these files I don't want to copy.

My `find` command is like this:

```
find . -type f -name "*????x????.???"
```

If I search with this I get the files I wanted to see, but if I combine this with `-exec cp`:

```
find . -type f -name "*????x????.???" -exec cp "{}" /home/mine/Pictures/WP \;
```

the `find` command only copies 10 files and there are 77 (I counted with `wc`).

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26234041/is-it-possible-to-pipe-the-results-of-find-to-a-copy-command-cp

Comment: it was helpful, but it doesnt seem to work with the subfolders

Comment: Maybe you have multiple directories each containing an image `1920x1080.jpg` and they get overwritten because you can't have two files with the same name in your destination directory.

Comment: omg...that makes sense...but how do i rename them in the find command? :D

Answer (score 0):

You can look it up if you follow the link.
[renaming with find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654819/renaming-with-find)
You can use -exec to do this. But i'm not sure you can do rename and copy in one take.Maybe with a script that got executed after every find result.

But that's only a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

One idea/approach is to copy absolute path of the file in question to the destination, but replace the `/` with an underscore `_` since `/` is not allowed in file names, at least in a Unix like environment.

With `find` and `bash`, Something like.

```
find /usr/share/wallpapers -type f -name "????x????.???" -exec bash -c '
   destination=/home/mine/Pictures/WP/
   shift
   for f; do
     path_name=${f%/*}
     file_name=${f##*/}
     echo cp -vi -- "$f" "$destination${path_name//\//_}$file_name"
   done' _ {} +
```

---

- See  [understanding-the-exec-option-of-find](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find)

---

With `globstar` `nullglob` shell option and Associative array from the `bash` shell to avoid the duplicate filenames.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s globstar nullglob
pics=(/usr/share/wallpapers/**/????x????.???)
shopt -u globstar nullglob

declare -A dups
destination=/home/mine/Pictures/WP/

for i in "${pics[@]}"; do
  ((!dups["${i##*/}"]++)) &&
  echo cp -vi -- "$i" "$destination"
done
```

---

- GNU `cp(1)` has the `-u` flag/option which might come in handy  along the way.
- Remove the `echo` if you're satisfied with the result.

---

Another option is to add a trailing `( )` with a number/int inside it and increment it , e.g. `????x????.???(N)` where `N` is a number/int. Pretty much like how some gui file manager deals with duplicate file/directory names.

Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

source=/usr/share/wallpapers/
destination=/home/mine/Pictures/WP/

while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
  counter=1
  file_name=${file##*/}
  if [[ ! -e "$destination$file_name" && ! -e "$destination$file_name($counter)" ]]; then
    cp -v -- "$file" "$destination$file_name"
  elif [[ -e "$destination$file_name" && ! -e "$destination$file_name($counter)" ]]; then
    cp -v -- "$file" "$destination$file_name($counter)"
  elif [[ -e "$destination$file_name" && -e "$destination$file_name($counter)" ]]; then
    while [[ -e "$destination$file_name($counter)" ]]; do
      ((counter++))
    done
    cp -v -- "$file" "$destination$file_name($counter)"
  fi
done < <(find "$source" -type f -name '????x????.???' -print0)
```

---

- Note that the `-print0` primary is a GNU/BSD `find(1)` feature.